# Is it possible to have multiple custom radio channels in GTA:San Andreas?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-san-andreas

Version of the game is PC, downgraded to 1.0

Instead of just the one custom radio channel the game has, is it possible to make multiple custom radio channels, so I could have different genres of custom music?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No**, but there's a way around that.

As you know, you can already use the **User Track Playlist**. That's the only place where you can just drop a file into the game to have your music being played.

**However:**

You can edit the other radios, in such a way that you replace GTA SA's audio files. Here's a guide [(original source linked)](http://gtaforums.com/topic/420579-gta-sa-radio-modding/)  on how to do it:

> - Download San Andreas Audio Toolkit [(SAAT)](http://www.gtagarage.com/mods/show.php?id=1186)
> - Put Saat_sfx,Saat_stream, metadata-full and metadata-generic in your GTA SA Folder.
> - Next, if you dont already have one, make a folder in C:\ called Temp. thats where we will extract the Sounds to.
> - go to command prompt (Run>Cmd) and then direct it to your GTA Folder for me this is "cd C:\Program Files\Rockstar Games\GTA San Andreas" but without quotes. in comand prompt type this :
>     saat_stream -e audio\streams** c:\temp\saat
>     Keep this open because we will need it later.
>     Where ** is type the name of the radio station you want to edit E.G CH
> - Next your gonna want to extract the sounds you want for you radio station, the radio names are different in the audio folder so ill list them below:
>
> AA - Police
>
> CH - PlayBack FM
>
> CO - KRose
>
> CR - K-DST
>
> DS - Bounce FM
>
> HC - SFUR
>
> MH - Radio Los Santos
>
> MR - Radio X
>
> NJ - CSR
>
> RE - K-Jah
>
> RG - Master Sounds
>
> TK - WCTR
>
> - Okay, now that you have your radio station extracted you need to replace the sounds with custom ones. Now say you want to replace Warm it up kane from PlayBack you can either open Warm It Up Kane(Mid).Ogg and replace it with the WHOLE of your custom song and have Warm it up kane(Intro, 1&2 and Outro 1&2) with a blank sound, Or you could split the song into parts the exact length of the original GTA parts.
> - Now we have to import the custom songs into GTA. To do this go back to Command Prompt and type this:
>     saat_stream -i audio\streams** c:\temp\saat**\stream_import.ini audio\CONFIG\TrakLkup.dat
>     Where ** is type the name of the radio station you want to edit E.G CH
>     Now just hold your breath and hope it works x]
>     if you have any problems just coment and ill try to help you wink.gif

Comment: Thank you, Oak. I was hoping to avoid replacing existing stations, but I'm sure I can find one or two stations I can live without. :)

Comment: I guess you could replace Police, but then again you'd have to mod so you get access to the Police Radio on all vehicles (or just drive cop cars everywhere :P). Personally I love WCTR, even if fictional those talk shows are great